# Creating a dictionary with nested list with reader + itertools (reading from txt file)

Tags: python

I have created this file and want the return-parameter be a dictionary with the form {animal name: [date, weight]...}

```
import itertools
import csv
        def readanimal(file):
      animal_map = {}
      with open(filnamn, encoding="utf-8") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t")

        for new_animal, rows in itertools.groupby(reader, lambda row: len(row) == 1):
          if new_animal:
            animal = next(rader)[0]
          else:
            animal_map[animal] = list(rows)
            del animal
      return(animal_map)
```

I read from a file with the following format:

```
Pig
21-10-26  96.58
21-10-27  95.35
21-10-28  94.36
21-10-29  94.00
21-11-01  93.26
21-11-02  91.93
21-11-03  93.52
21-11-04  93.58
21-11-05  95.00
21-11-08  95.36
21-11-09  95.89
21-11-10  96.26
Bear
21-10-22\t [weight] (for every date below)
21-10-25
21-10-26
21-10-27
21-10-28
21-10-29
21-11-01
21-11-02
21-11-03
21-11-04
21-11-05
```

But all I get is an empty dictionary when doing print(readanimal("filename.txt")). What have I done wrong?

Comment: There are multiple typos in the code you posted, any of which would stop it from running. Can you include a minimum reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `groupby` adds a lot of value here; it's easier to just keep track of which animal you're on as you add each row to the dictionary.  (It would be a lot easier of the type of animal was a column instead of a header row -- then you could indeed `groupby` that value and this would practically be a one-liner.)  For that matter, `csv` doesn't add much value compared to just using `split`.

Simplified input file `animals.txt` (since yours wasn't valid as-is):

```
Pig
21-10-26        96.58
21-10-27        95.35
Bear
21-10-22        100
21-10-25        100
```

and code that just builds the dict as I described:

```
def readanimal(filename):
    animal_map = {}
    current = []
    with open(filename) as file:
        for row in map(str.split, file):
            if len(row) == 1:
                current = []
                animal_map[row[0]] = current
            else:
                current.append(row)
    return animal_map


print(readanimal("animals.txt"))
```

prints:

```
{'Pig': [['21-10-26', '96.58'], ['21-10-27', '95.35']], 'Bear': [['21-10-22', '100'], ['21-10-25', '100']]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. What is wrong with the input file though? I know the "t [weight] (for every date below)" is wrong but I just wanted to be clear what it looks like. Is there anything else? Maybe that is why the program isn't working properly.

Comment: WIth the corrected code if something is wrong with the input file you should be able to tell what it is from the generated dictionary.

Comment: Yeah I get a dictionary like {'Pig': [], '21-10-22  99.67': [], '21-10-25  96.15': [], '21-10-26  96.58': [], '21-10-27  95.35': [], '21-10-28  94.36': [], '21-10-29  94.00': [], '21-11-01  93.26': [], '21-11-02  91.93': [], etc... but I can't see what is wrong with the file...

Comment: Sounds like the file isn't actually tab-delimited, so each line is being treated as a single column (hence an animal).  You might be better off just using `split()` than trying to treat this as a csv.